# How could I commit to remote branch one by one automatically

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following commits in my local branch,

the oldest is `17081fa`, the latest is `12ba64e`

How could I push these commits to remote git server one by one.

Take an example,

```
I don't want to push all local commits at once.

the push order should be

17081fa -> 30854d2 -> ... -> 12ba64e
```

These commits are ready to push to server, but need to be pushed one by one,

I need to know what's the command can let me do that way, thanks

```
* 12ba64e 
* 0fdf1a6 
* 75428a3 
* 00f837f 
* da9d16d 
* 3f34af9 
* b6066e9 
* cdf2dbf 
* 0d5cc8b 
* db8744c 
* df564b9 
* 30854d2 
* 17081fa
```

Comment: because i'm not be able to test the functionality on my local machine, push commits one by one to remote server, and trigger the CI can let me found the buggy commit quickly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply specify the full refspec when pushing:

```
git push origin 17081fa:branchname
git push origin 30854d2:branchname
# etc
```

---

If you want to automate it a bit, you could write a litte shell loop which waits for your keypress:

```
for hash in $(git rev-list 17081fa^..12ba64e); do
  read -p "Pushing $hash. Press return to continue.";
  git push origin $hash:branchname;
done
```